# Por que não posso chamar métodos direto em um número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Uma pergunta simples, mas está me deixando curioso.

Sei que no javascript tudo é warpado em algum construtor de objeto, por isso posso chamar métodos em strings mesmo a string não sendo um objeto em teoria. Então quando eu faço:

```
"Hello World".split(' ');
```

Eu estou chamando o método `split()` dentro do objeto `String` do javascript.

Minha pergunta é: por que numeros não são igualmente 'warpados'? Digo:

```
2.toString(); // não funciona

var dois = 2;
dois.toString; // '2'
```

Por que este comportamento?

@edit

Percebi que alguns métodos podem ser chamados diretamente em números, como por exemplo o `toFixed()` o que me deixa ainda mais curioso. O `toString()` não funciona por ser herdado de `Object`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pode sim! O problema é apenas a sintaxe do seu teste.

Perceba que com apenas um pequeno ajuste já funciona:

```js
console.log( (2).toString() );
```

O que acontece é que o interpretador não vai entender o ponto seguido de caracteres alfanuméricos, sendo que ele é já usado para separar decimais. Ao adicionarmos algo que descaracterize este uso (no exemplo, os parênteses), o interpretador não tem mais problemas com o ponto.

No caso do `.split()` já não vai funcionar, mas é pelo simples fato do método não existir para números:

```js
console.log( (432).split('') ); // Dá erro
```

Mas... veja isto - convertendo para string, o `split` passa a funcionar:

```js
console.log( (432).toString().split('') );
```

Os parênteses foram um exemplo, veja outras situações sem ambiguidade:

```js
console.log( 432 .toString().split('') );

console.log( 789.0.toString().split('') ); // o segundo ponto não dá confusao
```

(o exemplo com espaço foi sugerido pelo colega @jsbueno nos comentários)

Comment: Então no caso não funcionou por que ele considerou o ponto um separador de casas decimais e esperou outro número após ele? Muito interessante, obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 13):

Assim funciona:

```js
console.log((2).toString());
```

É uma questão de ambiguidade de sintaxe da linguagem. JS permite um número ser expressado como decimal sem preencher a parte decimal, ou seja, permite que se coloque só o número inteiro e um ponto e mais nada, o que criaria ambiguidade para a chamada do método que começa com ponto.

```js
console.log(2.);
console.log((2.).toString());
console.log(2.5.toString());
```

Como seria o certo? Ignorar o ponto decimal? Parece muito errado. Usar duas vezes o ponto? Estranho e impediria uma sintaxe que usasse esse padrão (*range*), então preferiu-se exigir que número literais só pudessem ser chamados por métodos dentro de parênteses ou com espaço entre o número e o ponto do método (ver crédito no comentário abaixo).

```js
console.log(2. .toString());
console.log(2 .toString());
//console.log(2.toString());
//console.log(2..toString());
```

Foi cometido um erro na linguagem para corrigir outro erro, era só JavaScript ter escolhido exigir que a parte decimal sempre fosse escrita explicitamente, mesmo que seja só um 0. Ela não exige, mas você pode fazer assim e evitar maiores problemas, por isso minha recomendação é sempre fazer assim para o seu caso, me parece o mais intuitivo e bate com outras linguagens:

```js
console.log(2.0.toString());
```

E de acordo com a edição na pergunta, o `toFixed()` também não permite, o problema é a sintaxe ambígua e nada com relação ao método em si ou objeto que ele pertence. Note que se você usar um decimal completo (inteiro mais parte decimal, dá para usar sem problemas):

```js
console.log(2.5.toString());
//console.log(2.toFixed());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Formatting.js).

Comment: Além do parênteses, um espaço entre o token numérico e o ponto para separar os métodos e propriedades funciona também.

Comment: @jsbueno essa eu não sabia, obrigado.

Comment: @Maniero o `toFixed` funcionou pra mim quando editei aquilo por que usei um numero decimal para fazer o teste, afinal usar o `toFixed` num numero inteiro não faz sentido. Quando editei aquilo fiz o teste assim: `2.73.toFixed()` e funcionou, por isso editei aquilo.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo acabei de editar que funciona até no `toString()`, quando tem a parte decimal não há ambiguidade na sintaxe, novamente o problema é de sintaxe e não de método, por isso fiz no `toString()` mesmo pra mostrar que neste caso funciona em todos métodos. Sua pergunta não menciona como fez, por isso fica difícil mostrar o real problema.