# Como o navegador percorre a cadeia de protótipos com string e array?

Tags: javascript

Para ilustrar minha pergunta e minha dúvida eu vou usar o seguinte exemplo bem simples:

```js
function Car(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

    this.phrase = function() {
      alert(`${this.name} ${this.age} a fast car`);
    };
}

let car1 = new Car('Ferrari', 2019);
```

No exemplo acima eu tenho duas propriedades e um método que são definidos na função construtora `Car()` estes são `name`, `age`, `phrase()` o que acontece é que o construtor `Car()` possui alguns outros métodos que já vem inclusos (por padrão) quando é criado o construtor `Car()` como, por exemplo, `toString()`, `valueOf()`, `toLocaleString()` e etc, caso eu chame estes métodos vai funcionar:

```
car1.toString()
car1.valueOf()
car1.toLocaleString()

// etc
```

Estes métodos não são definidos no construtor `Car()` e sim no seu próprio protótipo que é `Object()` e para que o navegador execute estes métodos que não estão definidos no construtor `Car()` ele sobe na cadeia de protótipos verificando se cada objeto de protótipo possui o método especificado, caso encontre ele vai executar:

**Verificando se o protótipo de `car1` possui o método especificado**

```
car1 > Car() > Não possui o método
```

**Verificando se o protótipo de `Car()` possui o método especificado**

```
car1 > Car() > Object() > Possui o método
```

No caso do JavaScript (pelo menos uma linguagem que eu saiba) não tem como você chamar um método usando a sintaxe de cima (notação de ponto) em um número como, por exemplo:

```
19.toFixed(3);
19.toExponential();
19.toPrecision(3);
```

Mas em strings e arrays tem como usar a sintaxe de cima:

```js
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c'].length;
let b = 'abc'.indexOf('g');

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

O que eu gostaria de entender é como que o navegador executa os métodos e propriedades em um array e string ou seja como que ele percorre pela cadeia de protótipos quando eu uso métodos de `Array` e `String` (como no primeiro exemplo).

Comment: Na verdade tem como chamar os métodos em números sim: `1 .toString()` (note o espaço entre o número é o ponto) ou `(1).toString()`, por exemplo. Isso porque o ponto logo em seguida do número é usado para denotar a sua parte fracionária.

Comment: Complementando o comentário acima, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362560/112052). Sobre a sua dúvida, já não foi respondido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/112052)? "*Ao invocar o método, o interpretador verifica se o objeto em questão possui um método com esse nome... Então o interpretador verifica se o protótipo de cada objeto possui o método... Caso o método não fosse encontrado, o interpretador continuaria a verificação subindo na cadeia de protótipos, até encontrar o método ou propriedade desejado, ou até chegar a um objeto que possua null como protótipo.*"

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%c3%b3tipos-em-javascript)

Comment: Realmente interessante não sabia destes pequenos detalhes ao chamar um método em um número, vlw.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, não! eu mesmo entendo como funciona os protótipos, mas com string e array me deixa confuso como, por exemplo, quando uma string é definida como que o navegador vai percorrer na cadeia de protótipos para atribuir o método a string? no momento em que eu defino a string ela já vai possuir os seus devidos métodos mesmo ela não sendo um objeto?

Comment: String e arrays tb são objetos, a diferença é que são nativos da linguagem, com todos os métodos já "pré-definidos". Mas o funcionamento é o mesmo, procura-se o método no protótipo do objeto, se não achar vai subindo na cadeia de protótipos, etc

Comment: Exemplo: https://ideone.com/h88jyn

Comment: @hkotsubo atá entendi eu achei que tinha uma forma em específico de subir na cadeia com strings e arrays :), mas obrigado.

Comment: Posso até elaborar uma resposta, mas esse argumento *"...não tem como você chamar um método usando a sintaxe de cima (notação de ponto) em um número como..."* eu vou refutar. Meu medo é perder  tempo reunindo material e produzir uma resposta teórica e acabar sendo ofendido. O pergunto, há algum problema em confrontar partes de sua pergunta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Ainda acho que é duplicada. É que ele achou que objetos nativos - como string e array - tinham tratamento diferenciado, mas já foi esclarecido que é igual ao que já foi explicado [aqui](/q/15239/112052). E sobre chamar método em número, já foi respondido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362560/112052). Não sei se tem mais o que acrescentar. E da forma que está a pergunta, entendo que é duplicada

Comment: @AugustoVasques, não sem problema algum.